# set the router's static mac address via isc-dhcp-server

Tags: linux, dhcp, arp, isc-dhcpd, spoofing

Is it possible to set an ip with its relative mac address so that the clients (during the DHCP request) in addition to receiving the various data, will also directly receive the mac address of the router in order to protect the device from an ARP Spoofing attack?

Is it possible via **isc-dhcp-server** or is there anything else needed?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of DHCP is to assign IP addresses and the way it works relies on the ARP protocol working correctly, that is MAC addresses are static and unique on a network segment.

Whilst you could use DHCP to push custom parameters and issue a message to the client saying which MAC address it *should* have, the work needs doing on the client side. In addition, if you conclude the MAC needs changing, then the DHCP negotiation needs repeating to have the correct IP address assigned (provided your DHCP server has a static mapping of that MAC to a specific IP).

From a security perspective, none of this holds up against an attacker on the network. There's no integrity validation or authentication in the DHCP protocol, therefore it can all be modified in transit and the spoofing attack achieved nonetheless. Or you could attack the DHCP server instead....